# Download Single Webform Submission CSV

Tags: 8, files, webforms, importing-exporting

I would like to download the webform submissions one by one.

Currently the core of Webform owns to download all submission data to a CSV.

***Webform -> Result -> Download***

How to download one submission data (by submisisons id for example) to a single CSV ?

Answer (score 2):

Under 'Download options' you can limit the CSV to a submission id.

[image]